# How to sort a set of objects according to Enum field in java

Tags: java, enums

guess we have enum like this

```
enum Role{ MANAGER, ADMIN, USER }
```

and also we have class

```
public class User{
     String userName;
     Role userRole;
}
```

then we have Set of users. I want to sort this user Set according to role enum.
Users with role as MANAGER must come first and users with the USER Role must go to the end of the set.

Comment: You mean you want to "sort" a set? Note that sets by default are not ordered or sorted so you'd need a `SortedSet` or an ordered collection like a list. Then use `role.ordinal()` in the comparator or `compareTo()` implementation of your user class. One side note: do yourself a favor and stick to the Java coding conventions, e.g. start class and enum names with an upper case letter (so `Role` and `User`).

Comment: @Thomas thank you for your advice can you please explain how to sort list like this

Comment: Well, have a look at `List.sort()` or `Collections.sort()`. Just provide the appropriate comparator and you should be good to go. If you're not familiar with comparators yet you might want to grab a tutorial on those as they are a fairly important and widely used concept.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you have the values in a list called `yourList`. Of course you can add to the set directly, if that fits your needs better.

```
SortedSet<User> set = new TreeSet<User>(Comparator.comparing(User::userRole)
   .thenComparing(User::userName));
set.addAll(yourList)
```

Answer (score 1):

Make `User` class implement `Comparable` interface like this:

```
public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        Set<User> set = new TreeSet<>();
        set.add(new User("a", Role.USER));
        set.add(new User("b", Role.MANAGER));
        set.add(new User("c", Role.ADMIN));
        
        System.out.println(set);
    }
}

enum Role{ MANAGER, ADMIN, USER }

class User implements Comparable<User> {
    String userName;
    Role userRole;
    
    public User(String name, Role role) {
        this.userName = name;
        this.userRole = role;
    }
    
    @Override
    public int compareTo(User o) {
        
        return this.userRole.compareTo(o.userRole);
    }
    
    public String toString() {
        return this.userName;
    }
}
```

Output:

```
[b, c, a]
```